# Can't format "Add Two Numbers" output correctly in Ruby (Singly Linked List)

Tags: ruby, singly-linked-list

Trying to solve leetcode's "Add Two Numbers" problem in Ruby (https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/). I know I have not solved the problem at all, just trying to make sure I can get my output in the correct "ListNode" format first. The ListNode I'm trying to add to keeps writing over itself because it's in the while loop but I have been working on this forever and cannot figure out how to get the output the way that leetcode wants it.

Any help is appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
# class ListNode
#     attr_accessor :val, :next
#     def initialize(val = 0)
#         @val = val
#         @next = nil
#     end
# end

# @param {ListNode} l1
# @param {ListNode} l2
# @return {ListNode}

def add_two_numbers(l1, l2)
    current_output = head = ListNode.new()
    while l1.next != nil
        sum = l1.val + l2.val
        if current_output.next != nil
            current_output = current_output.next
        else
            current_output.next = ListNode.new(sum)
            current_output.next = current_output.next.next
        end

        l1.val = l1.next.val
        l1.next = l1.next.next
        l2.val = l2.next.val
        l2.next = l2.next.next
    end
    last_sum = l1.val + l2.val
    #current_output.next = ListNode.new(last_sum)
    return current_output 
end
```

Note: It requires that the output be a ListNode object so I can't created my own LinkedList class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Classic solution**

```
def add_two_numbers(l1, l2)
  head = ListNode.new
  carry = 0
  curr = head

  until l1.nil? && l2.nil? && carry.zero?
    v1 = l1&.val || 0
    v2 = l2&.val || 0
    carry, digit = (v1 + v2 + carry).divmod(10)
    curr.next = ListNode.new(digit)
    curr = curr.next
    l1 = l1&.next
    l2 = l2&.next
  end

  head.next
end
```

Note that `l1` and `l2` may have different lengths, so you should end the loop when both nodes become `nil`.

In case you don't know the syntax `obj&.mthd`, it's called "safe navigation", which means if `obj` is `nil`, return `nil` immediately without calling `mthd` on it. If `obj` is not `nil`, return whatever `obj.mthd` returns.

**Cheating**

You can work out the integer each list represents, add them together, and build the result list based on the sum.

```
# Monkey-patch ListNode
# to make a list enumerable,
# so that we can call `reduce` on it.
ListNode.class_eval do
  include Enumerable

  def each(&block)
    return enum_for(:each) unless block
    block.(@val)
    @next.each(&block) if @next
  end
end

def add_two_numbers(l1, l2)
  n1 = l1.reduce(""){|s, n| "#{n}#{s}"}.to_i
  n2 = l2.reduce(""){|s, n| "#{n}#{s}"}.to_i

  head = ListNode.new
  (n1 + n2).digits.reduce(head) do |prev_node, digit|
    ListNode.new(digit).tap{|node| prev_node.next = node}
  end

  head.next
end
```

Comment: Oh I see, I had to return head at the end instead of current_output to display the full ListNode. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here is a code that sums two linked lists, then I will break it down so you can take part of it and use them, however it is not well tested as I just wrote it now after hacking into [this](https://medium.com/@zylberberg.jonathan/linked-lists-f656bd22f2fa) blog post and making little edits on it:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :next

  def initialize(value, next_node)
      @value = value
      @next = next_node
  end
end


class LinkedList
  include Enumerable
  def initialize
    @head = nil
  end

  def add_to_list(value)
    return @head = Node.new(value, nil) unless @head
    current_node = @head
    while current_node.next != nil
      current_node = current_node.next
    end
    current_node.next = Node.new(value, nil)
  end

  def each
    current = @head
    while current
      yield current.value
      current = current.next
    end
  end

  def to_i
    self.reduce(""){ |s, l| "#{l}#{s}" }.to_i
  end
end


list1 = LinkedList.new
list2 = LinkedList.new
sum = LinkedList.new

list1.add_to_list(2)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb54940 @value=2, @next=nil>
list1.add_to_list(4)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb545f8 @value=4, @next=nil>
list1.add_to_list(3)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb543a0 @value=3, @next=nil>

list2.add_to_list(5)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb54170 @value=5, @next=nil>
list2.add_to_list(6)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb7bf40 @value=6, @next=nil>
list2.add_to_list(4)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb7bd10 @value=4, @next=nil>

result = list1.to_i + list2.to_i  # => 807
result.digits.each do |i|
  sum.add_to_list(i)
end
puts list1.to_i  # => nil
puts list2.to_i  # => nil
puts sum.to_i  # => nil

# >> 342
# >> 465
# >> 807
```

in the code above the following is a definition of a node of the linked list:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :next

  def initialize(value, next_node)
      @value = value
      @next = next_node
  end
end
```

the node has a value attribute and a pointer to the node that comes after it in the linked list.

lets break down the linked list which has only two methods in it in this case:
the fist one is `add_to_list`:

```
  def add_to_list(value)
    return @head = Node.new(value, nil) unless @head
    current_node = @head
    while current_node.next != nil
      current_node = current_node.next
    end
    current_node.next = Node.new(value, nil)
  end
```

it takes an integer as a value then creates a node for it in the linked-list.

the second method is `to_i` which converts the linked list `backward` to an integer so later we can do `list1.to_i + list2.to_i` which gives us the sum of the two lists:

```
  def each
    current = @head
    while current
      yield current.value
      current = current.next
    end
  end

  def to_i
    self.reduce(""){ |s, l| "#{l}#{s}" }.to_i
  end
```

now lets come to the code that makes the actual calculation:

- here is the initialization of `list1, list2, and the sum lists`:

```
list1 = LinkedList.new
list2 = LinkedList.new
sum = LinkedList.new

list1.add_to_list(2)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb54940 @value=2, @next=nil>
list1.add_to_list(4)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb545f8 @value=4, @next=nil>
list1.add_to_list(3)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb543a0 @value=3, @next=nil>

list2.add_to_list(5)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb54170 @value=5, @next=nil>
list2.add_to_list(6)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb7bf40 @value=6, @next=nil>
list2.add_to_list(4)  # => #<Node:0x000055951cb7bd10 @value=4, @next=nil>
```

- and here is doing the actual sum of both `list1, and list2`:

```
result = list1.to_i + list2.to_i  # => 807
```

- here is the conversion of the `result` integer value to a linked list:

```
result.digits.each do |i|
  sum.add_to_list(i)
end
```

- and here is the content of `list1, list2, and sum` variables printed out:

```
puts list1.to_i  # => nil
puts list2.to_i  # => nil
puts sum.to_i  # => nil

# >> 342
# >> 465
# >> 807
```

so in your `add_two_numbers` method of the problem all what you want is to convert the two linked lists into integers in the proper way then make the sum of them, after then convert the resulting integer into a linked list which will be returned as the final solution, and make sure to run enough test cases and test the corner cases.

Comment: you can use the built in Linked list in ruby but use its api instead of the api of the linked list presented here.